# Firebase messaging only working in debug, but not in release mode (iOS)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-layout

I am using the flutter framework with the firebase messaging plugin to enable push notifications. Firebase messaging are working correctly on iOS when compiling my flutter app in debug mode. I haven't tried it on Android yet. But when I am compiling in release mode, no push notification appears. In Firebase, I have not filled in app-name and store-id yet, since the app is not release within the Apple AppStore yet. Might that be the issue?

Comment: what is app-name or store-id?  did u manage to fix it please?

Comment: Did you add you APN Key to your cloud messaging in firebase console? you need it and make sure to add the capability

Comment: That might be the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Also had this issue (`firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3`), spent few hours fixing it. For me worked two steps:

**FIRST**

change

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<true/>
```

to

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<string>NO</string>
```

in the `ios/Runner/Info.plist` file.

More info is here [flutter: fcm ios push notifications doesn't work in release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63782395/flutter-fcm-ios-push-notifications-doesnt-work-in-release-mode)

**SECOND**

When init pushes use this code

```
FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

if (Platform.isIOS) {
  firebaseMessaging.configure();
  userPermission = await firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you added Push Notification capability to all configurations and not only in debug mode:

1. Open Runner.xcworkspace with Xcode.
2. Go to Runner in Targets.
3. Go to “Signing & Capabilities”
4. Next to “+ Capability” select “All”.
5. Check that all configurations have “Push Notifications”.

Below my “Signing & Capabilities” screen from Xcode:

[image: My “Signing & Capabilities” screen from Xcode:]