# flutter: fcm ios push notifications doesn't work in release mode

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, release

I have bound my flutter-iOS app to firebase and i'm also using firebase-messaging and cloud functions for sending notifications via subscribing to topics, i'm using the APNs push notifications key of apple developer account. when i use the option runner>flutter run main.dart in release mode to build my app on my phone, fcm notifications doesn't work anymore, while it works in development mode, anyone can help me fix this?

this is my index.json code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
 
var newData;
 
exports.messageTrigger = functions.firestore.document('notifications/{notificationsId}').onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
newData = snapshot.data();
const payload = {
    notification: {
        title: newData.title,
        body: newData.body,
        sound: 'default'
    },
    
        data: {
      click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
      message: newData.title,
    }

};

if (newData.language === 'english'){
    await admin.messaging().sendToTopic('english', payload);
}
else if (newData.language === 'arabic'){
    await admin.messaging().sendToTopic('arabic', payload);
}
else if (newData.language === 'kurdish'){
    await admin.messaging().sendToTopic('kurdish', payload);
}
});
```

hence package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Make sure Push Notification Certification you have created supports production.

Comment: hello, thankyou, Ihaven't distributed it in the appstore yet, just build released on my phone, does that need a certificate too?

Comment: im not using push notifications certificate , im using APNS key

Comment: please send me firebase cloud messaging settings page  screenshot. where you added the apn

Comment: how do i send it? i have uploaded the apns key correctly to firebase, it works well on android debug and release as well as ios debug, the only problem is ios release mode

Comment: Android doesn't need APN keys. please send a link of the screenshot

Comment: Are you using firebase functions?

Comment: yes cloud functions

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/?id=A9051E0B1F070FD0%213418&cid=A9051E0B1F070FD0

Comment: show me the package.json file of the cloud function

Comment: i used index.json, its int the same link

Comment: The link is not working.  Please edit the question and add the package.json code and index.json code.

Comment: added them, thankyou

Answer (score 9):

My project got the same issue. Combined two solutions I found, it finally works. (firebase_messaging 7.0.3)

As for debug mode, you don't need these.

Step 1: Edit AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }
    
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Step 2: Edit ios/Runner/Info.plist. Add this:

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<string>NO</string>
```

Comment: I had similar issue
and just adding this 

     application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

solved my problem

Comment: Same problem application.registerForRemoteNotifications() solved my problem

Comment: this worked for me too. thanks

Answer (score 2):

After update firebase_messaging to 7.0.0 I had the same problem. I added application.registerForRemoteNotifications() in my AppDelegate.swift and it worked!

Comment: can you edit and write the complete app delegate please?

Comment: it gives me an error wherever i put it in my appdelegate

Comment: also mine is in Objective C

Comment: @azheen https://gist.github.com/kabazyba/cbc381aa504ab63a7de893236f77e9d2

Answer (score 1):

I tried many ways. I did deep research, when i give up i checked my Xcode Settings and i saw under Signing&Capabilities -> Debug -> Notification added but  Signing&Capabilities -> Release I didn't add.
so i added capability and it worked [look this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbBoN.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Looks like iOS release require additional notification params

To check that notification works you could try to send message directly from the firebase console.

Cloud Messaging -> Send your first message -> Enter notification title and text -> Send test message -> Enter your device token -> Test

To obtain device token you can use `print(await FirebaseMessaging().getToken());`

To check release logs connect the device and open Xcode -> Window -> Devices and Simulators -> Open Console

If it works you could try to add this params:

```
const payload = {
 notification: {
    title: newData.title,
    body: newData.body,
    sound: 'default'
 },
 data: {
    click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
    message: newData.title,
 },
 apns: {
    headers: { "apns-priority": "5" },
    payload: {
            aps: {
                contentAvailable: true,
                category: "NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY"
            }
        }
    },
};
```

But I'm not sure which param helps: `"apns-priority"` or `contentAvailable`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create appropriate certificates to enable Pushnotifcation in Release mode iOS

Note : Everything will run as expected in debug mode even if you don't have Provisional Profile Certificate. But It's mandatory in release mode

1. Apple SandBox Push service certificate
2. Provisional Profile Certificate
3. Apple Development, Distribution, Sigin Certificate all is mandatory

Follow the steps in the link : https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration/